# Subquery SUM with different date

Tags: mysql, sql

I retrieve two sum of value:

```
SUM (CASE WHEN CAUSALI.AVAILABLECAUSA_1 LIKE ('%CAUSE-1%')  THEN (mtscrap) ELSE 0 END ) as Cause1
```

and

```
SUM (CASE WHEN CAUSALI.AVAILABLECAUSA_1 LIKE ('%CAUSE-2%')  THEN (mtscrap) ELSE 0 END ) as Cause2
```

I would like to set another SUM statement without `%CAUSE-*`, and that have WHERE clause independent from the principal WHERE. I had innested this subquery:

```
(CASE WHEN day BETWEEN '2014-01-09' AND '2014-06-13' THEN SUM(MTSCRAP) ELSE 0 END) AS XXXXXX
```

but I have wrong data. My global query is:

```
    SELECT
      SezioneID
    , Desc_Prod
    , sample.products.VETTURA AS VetturaID
    , truncate((SUM(mtscrap_1) / SUM(MtProdotti_1)) * 100, 2) AS Scrap_1
    , truncate((SUM(mtscrap_2) / SUM(MtProdotti_2)) * 100, 2) AS Scrap_2
    , mtscrap_1
    , MtProdotti_1
    , mtscrap_2
    , MtProdotti_2
FROM flB.flB_prod AS PROD
      JOIN SAMPLE.PRODUCTS
                  ON (sample.products.SKU = PROD.SEZIONEID)
                        AND (sample.products.LINEA = 'FLB')
      JOIN (
                  SELECT
                        IDSEZIONE
                      , IDTURNO
                      , ID_PROG
                      , SUM(CASE
                              WHEN AVAILABLECAUSA_1 LIKE ('%CHANGE-1%') THEN mtscrap ELSE 0
                            END) AS mtscrap_1
                      , SUM(CASE
                              WHEN AVAILABLECAUSA_1 LIKE ('%CHANGE-1%') THEN MtProdotti ELSE 0
                            END) AS MtProdotti_1
                      , SUM(CASE
                              WHEN AVAILABLECAUSA_1 LIKE ('%CHANGE-2%') THEN mtscrap ELSE 0
                            END) AS mtscrap_2
                      , SUM(CASE
                              WHEN AVAILABLECAUSA_1 LIKE ('%CHANGE-2%') THEN  MtProdotti ELSE 0
                        END) AS MtProdotti_2
                            , MtProdotti
                  FROM FLB.flB_causali
                  WHERE DATASTARTPRG BETWEEN '2014-06-09' AND '2014-06-13'
                  GROUP BY
                        IDSEZIONE
                        IDTURNO
                      , ID_PROG
            ) AS CAUSALI
                  ON (PROD.SEZIONEID = CAUSALI.IDSEZIONE)
                        AND PROD.TURNO = CAUSALI.IDTURNO
                        AND PROD.ID_PROG = CAUSALI.ID_PROG
WHERE giorno BETWEEN '2014-06-09' AND '2014-06-13'
GROUP BY
      SezioneID
```

I need this view:[image: Required fields]

Comment: The square brackets on `[mtscrap]` betray this as not being MySQL, rather MS SQL Server or MS Access. What is your RDBMS really?

Comment: typing error I'm sorry. My RDBMS is MySql

Comment: Your attempt to use of DISTINCT inside a SUM() indicates to me your overall query is returning too many rows and you are hoping that distinct will sort that out for you. It will not.

Comment: please place table aliases against every field, for example we have no idea which tables mtscrap and MtProdotti come from

Comment: I'm doing a bit of confusion I'm sorry ... I replaced the query with the suggested, where there are the aliases against field name

Comment: oh dear, is my query correct? I don't know if it is... which table(s) have the field SezioneID? if it more than one then the query will fail. You need to specify table.field or tablealias.field :: do you understand?

Answer (score 1):

I have done my best to put a table or alias beside **EVERY** field reference. At this point I really do not know what else I can do for you. I don't think any more words will help.

these 2 simple items will help:
1. sample data
2. expected result

---

Because you did not use table aliases on all fields *in the very original query* **the following is a complete guess**, but using the presence of DISTINCT in that original query was a clue for "too many rows" that indicated the need for grouping prior to the overall query. So, here's my first guess:

```
SELECT
      PROD.SezioneID
    , PROD.Desc_Prod
    , sample.products.VETTURA AS VetturaID
    , truncate((SUM(CAUSALI.mtscrap_1) / SUM(CAUSALI.MtProdotti_1)) * 100, 2) AS Scrap_1
    , truncate((SUM(CAUSALI.mtscrap_2) / SUM(CAUSALI.MtProdotti_2)) * 100, 2) AS Scrap_2
    , CAUSALI.mtscrap_1
    , CAUSALI.MtProdotti_1
    , CAUSALI.mtscrap_2
    , CAUSALI.MtProdotti_2
FROM flB.flB_prod AS PROD
      JOIN SAMPLE.PRODUCTS
                  ON (sample.products.SKU = PROD.SEZIONEID)
                        AND (sample.products.LINEA = 'FLB')
      JOIN (
                  SELECT
                        flB_causali.IDSEZIONE
                      , flB_causali.IDTURNO
                      , flB_causali.ID_PROG
                      , SUM(CASE
                              WHEN flB_causali.AVAILABLECAUSA_1 LIKE ('%CHANGE-1%') THEN flB_causali.mtscrap ELSE 0
                            END) AS mtscrap_1
                      , SUM(CASE
                              WHEN flB_causali.AVAILABLECAUSA_1 LIKE ('%CHANGE-1%') THEN flB_causali.MtProdotti ELSE 0
                            END) AS MtProdotti_1
                      , SUM(CASE
                              WHEN flB_causali.AVAILABLECAUSA_1 LIKE ('%CHANGE-2%') THEN flB_causali.mtscrap ELSE 0
                            END) AS mtscrap_2
                      , SUM(CASE
                              WHEN flB_causali.AVAILABLECAUSA_1 LIKE ('%CHANGE-2%') THEN  flB_causali.MtProdotti ELSE 0
                        END) AS MtProdotti_2
                            , flB_causali.MtProdotti
                  FROM FLB.flB_causali
                  WHERE flB_causali.DATASTARTPRG BETWEEN '2014-06-09' AND '2014-06-13'
                  GROUP BY
                        flB_causali.IDSEZIONE
                        flB_causali.IDTURNO
                      , flB_causali.ID_PROG
            ) AS CAUSALI
                  ON (PROD.SEZIONEID = CAUSALI.IDSEZIONE)
                        AND PROD.TURNO = CAUSALI.IDTURNO
                        AND PROD.ID_PROG = CAUSALI.ID_PROG
WHERE PROD.giorno BETWEEN '2014-06-09' AND '2014-06-13'
GROUP BY
      PROD.SezioneID
;
```

Comment: Hello, I had try your suggest, but 'mtscrap_1' and 'mtscrap_2' in subquery SELECT steatement are not calculate, are not show in final result set

Comment: no they would not show in final result because they form part of  final calculation - but it is a guess. The idea is for you to tell us if the guess is inaccurate. Does the subquery - by itself work?

Comment: ok, I apologize if I was not clear in explaining my problem. I should have as a result of the computation that is performed by the SELECT statement after the JOIN, specifying other dates different from external WHERE clause. The query in this way does not work as it should, because not shows the results of the subquery.

Comment: regret to say I didn't understand any of that. you best bet is to avoid words, provide "sample data" and "expected result"

Comment: Hello, I'm sorry if I'm not more clear...I have included in my question a screenshot of the fields that I need as a result of the query

Comment: You don't know how to add more fields into the select clause? I have added 4 more columns like your scrennshot

Comment: yes I know, but the query that you have suggest me not show the red column like the screenshot...I'm sorry again for the patience

Comment: no problem, I'll do what I can, but my italian is too poor to use, also I am now going to bed (11:37pm)

Comment: do not assume my query is correct - it was a guess - I really need you to specify which table every field comes from - buonanotte

Comment: ok, I appreciate your kindness ... good night ... here (3:42pm)

Comment: FLB.FLB_PROD has the following fields: 'SezioneID , Desc_Prod, TURNO', FLB.FLB_CAUSALI has the following fields:'AVAILABLECAUSA_1,DATASTARTPRG,IDSEZIONE,ID_PROG'. sample.products has 'VETTURA' field. I hope that can help

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this expression?

```
SUM(CASE WHEN day BETWEEN '2014-01-09' AND '2014-06-13' THEN MTSCRAP ELSE 0 END) AS XXXXXX
```

The `CASE` goes inside the `SUM()` for conditional aggregation.

Comment: hello, I'd set this expression, but the data that are retrieved aren't correct, it's sound like that the WHEN have no validity,